# play command for view the running project console

Tags: amazon-web-services, playframework, console, web-hosting, playframework-2.2

I compiled my project.

```
play compile
```

then I started it in `Production mode` by,

```
play start
```

Then after some time i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

So now I can't view the **console**.

Is there any `play command` to view console?

OR i have to `stop` it and `start` again?

note: on AWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De facto Play console is not supposed to be used on production machine, instead you should prepare a [`dist`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionDist) distrubution and use i.e. log file for controlling logs (probably with `tail` command)

Comment: @biesor means not possible